# Save coordinates every x time using backgroundGeolocation and IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, geolocation

Good afternoon mates.

I'm doing an app with Ionic 2 using the `backgroundGeolocation` plugin and I want to send coordinates every `x` time as the [Cordova documentation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/blob/master/docs/README.md#config-integer-millis-locationupdateinterval) explains:

> [Geolocation] Android Options
>   `@config {Integer millis} locationUpdateInterval`
>
> ⚠️ To use `locationUpdateInterval` you must also configure `distanceFilter: 0`. `distanceFilter` overrides `locationUpdateInterval`.
>
> Set the desired interval for active location updates, in milliseconds.
>
> The location client will actively try to obtain location updates for your application at this interval, so it has a direct influence on the amount of power used by your application. Choose your interval wisely.
>
> This interval is inexact. You may not receive updates at all (if no location sources are available), or you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive them faster than requested (if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval).
>
> Applications with only the coarse location permission may have their interval silently throttled.

```
BackgroundGeolocation.configure({
  distanceFilter: 0,            // Must be 0 or locationUpdateInterval is 
  ignored!
  locationUpdateInterval: 5000  // Get a location every 5 seconds
});
```

But I can not find the way to do the same configuration using IONIC. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to leverage observable returned by watchPosition method:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/#watchPosition

Since its observable you can pipe it and set interval that you need:

```
const subscription = this.geolocation.watchPosition()
                              .pipe(debounceTime(500)); // import relevant rxjs operator
                              .subscribe(position => {
  console.log(position.coords.longitude + ' ' + position.coords.latitude);
});

// To stop notifications
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Please share your code if you want specifics.

Comment: hello sergey actually i started learning ionic , i need help with one of my code , hope getting your positive response soon on my question -   [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958509/log-the-coordinates-update-within-sec-in-inonic]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958509/log-the-coordinates-update-within-sec-in-inonic

Comment: hey the link says 404;/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958509/log-the-coordinates-update-within-sec-in-inonic                recheck it