# log the coordinates, update within sec. in Ionic

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic-native

Here is my code which logs the location but the update time is 5sec and I want to reduce it to around 500ms. the  app is working properly just want to reduce the time

```
  import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Geolocation } = Plugins;
import { NativeGeocoder, NativeGeocoderResult, NativeGeocoderOptions } from '@ionic-native/native-geocoder/ngx';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab3',
  templateUrl: 'tab3.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab3.page.scss']
})
export class Tab3Page {
  public lat: any;
  public lng: any;
  points: any;
  wait: any;
  constructor(public ngZone: NgZone) { 
    this.points = [];
  }
  track() {
    this.wait = Geolocation.watchPosition({}, (position, err) => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
        let date = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
        this.addNewLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude,date);
      })
    })
  }
  stopTracking() {
    Geolocation.clearWatch({ id: this.wait });
  }
  addNewLocation(lat, lng, time) {
    this.points.unshift({
      lat,
      lng,
      time,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone share with me why one would want to watch a location ? I do not see the use case scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to leverage [the timeout option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions/timeout):

> The PositionOptions.timeout property is a positive long value
> representing the maximum length of time (in milliseconds) the device
> is allowed to take in order to return a position. The default value is
> Infinity, meaning that getCurrentPosition() won't return until the
> position is available.

You can use it like so:

```
track() {
    this.wait = Geolocation.watchPosition({ enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 500, maximumAge: 0 }, (position, err) => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
        let date = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
        this.addNewLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude,date);
      })
    })
  }
```

Capacitor docs also confirm this should work: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/geolocation#type-162408

If the watchPosition method is not helping your use case you could try implementing your own "watch" method. Unfortunately I do not have access to an app with capacitor, but something like the below should get you on the right track:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Geolocation } = Plugins;
import { NativeGeocoder, NativeGeocoderResult, NativeGeocoderOptions } from '@ionic-native/native-geocoder/ngx';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab3',
  templateUrl: 'tab3.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab3.page.scss']
})
export class Tab3Page {

  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(public ngZone: NgZone) { 
  }

  track() {
    const interval500 = interval(500);
    this.subscription = interval500.pipe(
        concatMap(val => Geolocation.getCurrentPosition())
    ).subscribe(coordinates => console.log(coordinates));
  }

  stopTracking() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Basically you ll need your own interval (500ms) and then calling getCurrentPosition method for each "tick" of the interval. Then unsubscribing duly.

This is really not recommended way as this will cause battery issues etc.
Also the device might not be able to supply the geo data still if it has device level limitation on amount of updates.

Depending on the use case you might want to "approximate" geo data in between 5 second intervals instead.

Comment: I tried it but in android its still 5sec update time . do you know the reason for this?

Comment: I see, it could be the limitation they put on the device side. You should then implement your own "watch" method - basically leverage rxjs and interval operator and poke the geo data using getCurrentPosition. Keep in mind that poking it 2 times a second could drain the battery. I could try to write the method that would do that later today

Comment: sergy look forward to see your response ....im waiting for your positive reply with a great code . thank hope you turn in soon . humble request to help me with your method  @SergeyRudenko

Comment: hey @anshul sorry I do not have access to Capacitor app to even confirm the above update would work. Plus the devices may have device level limit on amount of time the update geoposition. But try it out and let me know.

Comment: @sergerrudenko did you check my code bro ?  i searched web and tried many ways  but still same . pls help me broo

Comment: did you look to my codes bro do u have any solutions for it bro ?????

Comment: so the only thing to try is to implement your own watch. I can't run code with capacitor on any of my pcs:/ see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-6cvhqg. I created "fake" getPosition call. So you should jus replace it with the getPosition call. Can you try that? https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/geolocation#method-getCurrentPosition-0

Comment: also update the code in the answer. Please try that. I forgot that concatMap needs to return Promise or Observable to the chain. See how I changed the code in the answer.

Comment: i tried what you all said but still it have 5sec update time. whats is the issue . is it with capictor . any suggestions that i can solve it , using Cordova or react native ? . due u have any other method bro ????? @sergey

Comment: it might be then hardware layer restriction governed by the OS (Android). Not sure if you can work around it other than writing your own Capacitor plugin, which I am not sure is optimal here. whats your use case? why do you need data in such small intervals?

Comment: actually , trying to build live running tracking app . writing own capacitor plugin ? what u mean by this

Comment: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins - basically you would write some native code + wrapper that exposes such plugin via js. This is in case you find that native APIs give you the ability to query geo location every 500ms. If you are making a running tracking app - no one will use your app if it actually gets data every 500ms cause your app will drain smartphone battery in like 30 mins. Best is to figure out the way to still do the tracking using once every 5 s data by using interpolation technique (coord A -> interpolated coords -> coord Z)

Comment: oh thanks mate @sergey . can you help me with a javascript have you work with it ?. can I have your mail or insta id . I really want to learn from you. dont worry i wont text you everyday or every time . i will only ask when im not able to find any documentation online or any related problems . it will be really helpfull if you give me.  and yeah you are right  that 5sec is fine thanks for your reply bro